# How to pass a dropdown selected value through jquery autocomplete function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-autocomplete

have a autocomplete function through which i pass the prefix letter from .aspx page,but how to pass a dropdown selected value?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=ALkTxt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/Getp") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=CmbHdn.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });

});



</script>
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code ? did u try to debug it ?

Comment: @Sora i want to add another parameter to the function to pass to webservice i.e. dropdown selected value

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what you want as i understand you want to send another parameter to the autocomplete function :

```
  var selectdval = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
  data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "','SelectedVal:'" + selectdval + "'}";
```

where `$("#myselect option:selected" ).val();` is the dropdown selectedValue

Comment: u should fix some quotation though but i had no time to fix them heheh lazy person ^-^ if you find my answer correct please accept it

Answer (score -1):

Try this `data: { 'prefix': request.term },` instead of `data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",`

Update,

use this function to send the selected value,

```
select: function (e, i) {



$.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/Getp") %>',
                data: { 'prefix': i.item.value },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
            },
```

Comment: Its only to send one value,how to send a dropdown selected value with the above.

Comment: @son I updated my answer, use `select` function to send the selected value like this `{ 'prefix': i.item.value }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer....but i want the prefix parameter to b as it is,want to add new parameter i.e dropdown selected value to the webservice method

Comment: Try this `{ 'prefix': 'some', 'selected': i.item.value }`